# Force between 2 plates of a capacitors , which approach is correct?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

If I have a parallel plate capacitor with charge $Q$, to calculate the force on first plate we say the electric field of $\frac{Q}{2\epsilon_0 A}$ is created by the second plate and since the charge on the first plate is Q the total force experienced by it is $\frac{Q^2}{2\epsilon_0 A}$ [image: Like this]

But if I consider on the first plate an elemental charge $dQ$ then it has no contribution on net electric field , so the net field is $\frac{Q}{\epsilon_0 A}$ and the net force on the particle is $\frac{Q dq}{\epsilon_0 A}$, and thus total force should be $\frac{Q^2}{\epsilon_0 A}$ [image]

What am I missing here ?? Where am I going wrong ??

Comment: Are you asking about the force between two charged planes? Your title is confusing.

Comment: Would you please elaborate more with a diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are missing here is that the E field contribution of palate 1 starts after the charge , thus the net field that is experienced by plate 2 is just the half on the net field and thus Force in expression 1 is correct. Nonetheless if you are not convinced , you can also visualise that you have also added the action reaction pairs in the expression too.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument is wrong. The charges on the plates do not experience total field of the same magnitude that is between the plates. The field that any little charge on the plate experiences is one half of that field. This is because the forces due to charges on the same plate cancel each other, so any little charge on one plate experiences net force due to charges on the other plate only.

Answer (score 0):

by using the second argument you also included the contribution of the charge of the plate on which you are calculating the force due to other and that is wrong

Comment: Is this an actual quote from some source? If so, you should cite it; if not, why is the text surrounded with unnecessary quotation marks?

Comment: Happy @ Kyle Kanos 